# How can we use jtable functions like tablemodel, tablecelleditor, tablerendere etc in JSP?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

since i am creating swing based applications in that using various functions of jtable like Tablecellrenderer, Tablecelleditor , Extends  Tablemodel, input validation, dynamically cell edit, un editable handling, display database data and store the jtable values to database etc.so please suggest , can i use all these functions of jtable in jsp. Using html for  creating table in jsp , then how can i use functions of  jtable in html table

Comment: *"so please suggest , can i use all these functions of jtable in jsp"* only in a `JApplet`. On that matter, see [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: See also [tag:jquery-jtable].